# how to change the CSS for a pardot form?

Tags: page-layout, css, form, pardot

I've created a form in Pardot and the style is perfect right now , I just need to change the style for 2 of the elements in this registration form. it's a calendar field that I need to change the CSS for it's background color , font color and some details like this. I attached a screenshot to give you a better view about the problem.
can anybody help me?
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override the styling on the form you can add specific styling to the landing page template.

Here's an example how you'd add background color for the calendar.

```
<style>#ui-datepicker-div {background-color: #897934!important;}</style>
```